# Check if document.GetElementById("").value does not contain null

Tags: javascript, getelementbyid, null-check

I am trying to check below condition,

```
var param= document.getElementById("txtbox").value;
if(param!== null  || param.length!==0 || param !=="" || param!==undefined)
{//do something}
```

but even if param is null it is entering in the if block. Does anyone have an idea about this?

Comment: Just check `param !== ''` only, the other checks are meaningless.

Comment: Even checking that.. it still enters if block.. But it should not

Comment: What element is `#txtbox`?

Comment: It shouldn't be possible for `document.getElementById("txtbox").value` to be `null`. I can't think of any situation where it wouldn't be `undefined` (because the element doesn't have a `value` property at all) or a string. You need to provide a [mcve].

Comment: @Quentin Maybe `value` is a custom property, and set to `null` ..?

Comment: @Teemu — Custom property maybe, but not a custom attribute (which would be invalid HTML and generate a string). An [mcve] would answer that though.

Comment: @FaranSaleem If `#txtbox` is an empty input element or a textarea element, its value is the empty string. In that case you should make a strict comparison to the empty string only, checking other alternatives with logical OR will make the check useless, because some of them will pass in all cases, nevertheless the value of `param`.

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
var param= document.getElementById("txtbox");
if(!param && !param.value)
{
    //do something
}
```

Comment: dont you want the oposite if (!!param && !!param.value)

Comment: `!param` passes if the element does not exist. Then it tries to check the value of som falsy value, which will trigger an error.

Comment: @faransaleem : agree with salahakbari, the order of your tests is really strange, you can't test first param.length!==0 and THEN param !=="". First check if param exists, then check its length property (logic here)

Answer (score 0):

You can `null` check element like,

```js
function checkNull() {
    var param= document.getElementById("txtbox").value;
    if(!param)
      console.log("Null check passed")    
    else
      console.log(param+" Entered by user")
  }
```

```html
<input type="text" id="txtbox" name="txtbox">
<button onclick="checkNull()">Null checker</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

unfortunely your code's logic is incorrect.

For example if param is null, param!=="" is true. Because null is different "" (empty string) and etc.

You may check only param variable.

For example:

```
var param= document.getElementById("txtbox").value;
if(param)
{//do something}
```

But also document.getElementById("txtbox") may be null or undefined, therefore you must check it.

For example:

```
var txtBox= document.getElementById("txtbox");
    if(txtBox&&txtBox.value)
    {//do something}
```

Comment: what if dcument.getElementById("txtbox") is null, youll get an error null.value....

Comment: @EugenSunic My answer was for the code in question, which didt'n check DOM element

Answer (score -1):

document.getElementById will return you single object that is representing first element with wanted ID, and it will return null if there is no element founded sou:

if(!param) {}

should be enough